# Issue with XSL loops and linefeeds

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml document of Worker records I have to loop thru the xml document and select records which match certain criteria. For each match I need to write a line to an output file followed by a newline (except for the last record as an empty line at EOF will break in the downstream system). Some records will match multiple criteria... Here is where I am having some difficulty please sample code below.. And thank you in advance for any help..

RESULT
SMITH(linebreak)
Smith - FulltimeSMITH(linebreak)
SMITH(linebreak)
Jones - Fulltime

EXPECTED RESULT
SMITH    (linebreak)
Smith - Fulltime    (linebreak)
SMITH    (linebreak)
SMITH    (linebreak)
Jones - Fulltime

Thanks in advance for any advice...

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Worker_Sync>


    <Worker>
        - <Group name="Employee Changes">
            <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
            <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
            <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
            <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
        </Group>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        - <Group name="Employee Changes">
            <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
            <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
            <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
            <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
        </Group>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        - <Group name="Employee Changes">
            <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
            <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
            <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
            <Field name="Fulltime">True</Field>
        </Group>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        - <Group name="Employee Changes">
            <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
            <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
            <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
            <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
        </Group>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        - <Group name="Employee Changes">
            <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
            <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
            <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
            <Field name="Fulltime">True</Field> 
        </Group>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        - <Group name="Employee Changes">
            <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
            <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
            <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
            <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
        </Group>
    </Worker>
</Worker_Sync>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Worker_Sync/Worker/Group[Field[@name='LastName']='Smith' 
            or 
            Field[@name='Fulltime']='True']">            
            <xsl:if test="Field[@name='Fulltime']='True'">
                <xsl:value-of select="Field[@name='LastName']"/>  <xsl:text> - Fulltime</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="Field[@name='LastName']='Smith'">
                <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(Field[@name='LastName'])"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

NEW XML

```
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">True</Field>
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">True</Field> 
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Smith</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
    </Group>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    - <Group name="Employee Changes">
        <Field name="LastName">Jones</Field> 
        <Field name="OriginalHireDt">03211977</Field> 
        <Field name="ParticipationDt">05011977</Field>
        <Field name="Fulltime">False</Field>
    </Group>
</Worker>
```

Comment: Can you please give the output you are getting and the expected result for the latest XML you have given ?

Answer (score 0):

What I beleive that this should be the solution to it as you need **a break after every match**  so I would suggest you this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Worker_Sync/Worker/Group[Field[@name='LastName']='Smith' 
        or 
        Field[@name='Fulltime']='True']">            
        <xsl:if test="Field[@name='Fulltime']='True'">
            <xsl:value-of select="Field[@name='LastName']"/>  <xsl:text> - Fulltime</xsl:text>
<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="Field[@name='LastName']='Smith'">
            <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(Field[@name='LastName'])"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks - this works with the xml provided but if the xml changes slightly which it will in my case (new xml added above to original post) after the Jones - Fulltime record and extra linefeed is added..

Comment: Can you please give the output you are getting and the expected result for the latest XML you have given ?